# how do I select only shell scripts from a collection of files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I want to find all my bash scripts (i have accumulated many of them now) and run them all through `bash -n` automatically.

What's a quick way to do this? I'd like to have `grep` match only the files whose first non blank lines start with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`...

A serviceable answer is of course something along the lines of

```
for file in *; do 
    if head -n 5 $file | grep "#!.*sh$" > /dev/null; then
        bash -n $file
    fi
done
```

But for the sake of "correctness" how might I reasonably do my grep on **only the first non-whitespace (or alternatively non-blank)** line?

Comment: The `file` command will tell you better than grep if something is a shell script or not. I can tell you that the limited checking that `bash -n` can provide over a set of scripts is so weak as to be useless; most interpreted languages are very hard (impossible?) to provide much by static analysis.

Comment: well. I'll take anything i can get, if it knows about a glaring syntax error, it's helpful to me. I'll look into `file`, thanks

Comment: There's no reason to look for “the first non-blank lines”.  The `#!` (“shebang”) must be the first characters of the first line of the file.  Thus it is sufficient to look at the first line of the file.

Comment: @robmayoff Ah, thanks. Didn't know that. But now that I want to know how to do it, I must know.

Comment: @msw You should post the recommendation of the `file` command as an answer.

Comment: Yes the `file` solution is what I went with actually. It is more semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using find:

```
     find . -type f -exec grep -e "^#\!\/bin\/.*sh$" {} +
```

Comment: @jaypal, sure? I thought that `+` will be more efficient. `+` will pass every file (as much as it can be) to `grep`. `\;` instead will invoke `grep` for each individual file.

Comment: Yes, `+` is efficient since OP mentioned he has a lot of files and using `+` will pass filenames in batches where as `{} \;` will pass one file at a time. I up-voted your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

With **`GNU awk`**

```
awk '
FNR==1 && $0~/#!\/bin\/sh|#!\/usr\/bin\/env sh|#!\/usr\/bin\/env bash|#!\/bin\/bash/ { 
    print FILENAME " is shell script";
}
FNR>1 {
    nextfile
}' *
```

- You can play around with the above `regex` and reduce it to just `#!`.
- `FNR==1` along with the `regex` would ensure that the first line is checked for `she-bang` line.
- `nextfile` would ensure that no file is looked beyond first line.
- `print` if just for logging.
- `FILENAME` will print the name of the file under inspection.
- `*` will glob to all files under working directory.

Comment: @StevenLu The only thing scary about `awk` is the name. :)

Comment: `nextfile` is only called if the first line matches.